# Perl syntax error - elseif should be elsif at

Tags: perl, syntax

Any ideas of what I need to change in this Perl code?

perl -wc yields:

```
elseif should be elsif at cgitelnet-mod.pl line 410.
syntax error at cgitelnet-mod.pl line 411, near ")
    {"
syntax error at cgitelnet-mod.pl line 444, near "else"
syntax error at cgitelnet-mod.pl line 453, near "}"
Illegal declaration of subroutine main::PrintDownloadLinkPage at cgitelnet-mod.pl line 461.
```

Whole file can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/7r5pfW5y

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It says "elseif" should be elsif". One idea would be to change where you've said "elseif" to say "elsif" instead.

Comment: That would be one idea yes... can I delete questions as if they never existed... :) thanks for the answer.

Comment: I don't think you need to delete it. We all make simple mistakes from time to time, don't beat yourself up about it. Next time, you will know how to interpret this error.

Answer (score 13):

You misspelled `elsif`. It is not `else`-`if`, remove the extra `e` and you should be fine.

Comment: If this answer answers your question, you should mark it with the checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the second e in elseif....Unlike many languages Perl spells it as elsif

Comment: Many? The `if` statement of C, C++, Java and JavaScript don't have such a clause. VisualBasic and Python use `elseif`. Perl and Ruby use `elsif`. Python, `sh` and `bash` use `elif`.

Comment: Yes "many" - you just listed two languages that spell it as elsif and "many" others that do not.  By the way C, C++, Java, and JavaScript all have an "else if" clause...not to mention my answer did not state how the proper syntax is in other languages, merely how the syntax is *not* (and as you pointed out most do not use "elsif").

Comment: You may have *meant* to say that there is no standard way of spelling `elseif`, but what you said has drastically different implications. It does not simply mean what you said it does. I believe that is now clarified by the comment I posted, though, so all's good.

Comment: No, C, C++, Java, and JavaScript don't have an "else if" clause. That `if` is start of a statement that has nothing to do with the `else`. If it does have an `else if` clause, then it also has an `else for` clause (`if (x) y(); else for (...) { ... }`) and an `else z()` clause (`if (x) y(); else z();`).